# Angular and huge webpack bundle.js

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to understand why webpack produces such huge files of my simple Angular setup.

I wanted to try to make the [Angular 5 min quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#) with webpack.

The 5 min quickstart includes in the html 3 vendor scripts, the following files (it actually includes 4 files, but the last is for system.js which I do not need in my webpack setup):

```
ff$ ls -lh node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js 
-rw-r--r--  1 ff  staff   116K Dec 15 21:12 node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js
-rw-r--r--  1 ff  staff   1.0M Dec 15 21:12 node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js
-rw-r--r--  1 ff  staff   363K Dec 15 02:44 node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js
```

And these files are not minimized, a total of around 1.5MB.

But when I run my webpack script:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/boot.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

It results in the following two files:

```
ff$ ls  -lh bundle*
-rw-r--r--  1 ff  staff   4.0M Jan 20 19:14 bundle.js
-rw-r--r--  1 ff  staff   4.2M Jan 20 19:14 bundle.js.map
```

Why are the bundle files so much giganticer than the vendor scripts that the 5 min quickstart includes? My part of this bundle is only a few bytes...

This is the output when I run the webpack command:

```
ff$ webpack --display-modules
ts-loader: Using typescript@1.7.5 and /Users/ff/testing/tsconfig.json
Hash: 9d7f1ef3b0818c188e33
Version: webpack 1.12.11
Time: 4823ms
Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  4.19 MB       0  [emitted]  main
bundle.js.map  4.45 MB       0  [emitted]  main
    [0] ./src/boot.ts 195 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] ./~/angular2/platform/browser.js 13.1 kB {0} [built]
    [2] ./~/angular2/src/core/angular_entrypoint.js 3.1 kB {0} [built]
    [3] ./~/angular2/src/facade/lang.js 51 kB {0} [built]
    [4] ./~/angular2/src/platform/browser_common.js 13.3 kB {0} [built]
    [5] ./~/angular2/src/core/di.js 4.34 kB {0} [built]
    [6] ./~/angular2/src/core/di/metadata.js 20.5 kB {0} [built]
    [7] ./~/angular2/src/core/di/decorators.js 4.24 kB {0} [built]
    [8] ./~/angular2/src/core/util/decorators.js 31.9 kB {0} [built]
    [9] ./~/angular2/src/core/di/forward_ref.js 4.78 kB {0} [built]
    [10] ./~/angular2/src/core/di/injector.js 128 kB {0} [built]
    [11] ./~/angular2/src/facade/collection.js 45.7 kB {0} [built]
    [12] ./~/angular2/src/core/di/provider.js 66 kB {0} [built]
    [13] ./~/angular2/src/facade/exceptions.js 7.99 kB {0} [built]
    [14] ./~/angular2/src/facade/exception_handler.js 18.3 kB {0} [built]
    [15] ./~/angular2/src/core/reflection/reflection.js 1.57 kB {0} [built]
    [16] ./~/angular2/src/core/reflection/reflector.js 22.2 kB {0} [built]
    [17] ./~/angular2/src/core/reflection/reflection_capabilities.js 35.3 kB {0} [built]
    [18] ./~/angular2/src/core/di/key.js 8.43 kB {0} [built]
    [19] ./~/angular2/src/core/di/type_literal.js 1.38 kB {0} [built]
    [20] ./~/angular2/src/core/di/exceptions.js 29.4 kB {0} [built]
    [21] ./~/angular2/src/core/di/opaque_token.js 3.83 kB {0} [built]
    [22] ./~/angular2/core.js 4.54 kB {0} [built]
    [23] ./~/angular2/src/core/metadata.js 82.6 kB {0} [built]
    [24] ./~/angular2/src/core/metadata/di.js 32.1 kB {0} [built]
    [25] ./~/angular2/src/core/metadata/directives.js 84.6 kB {0} [built]
    [26] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection.js 1.83 kB {0} [built]
    [27] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/change_detection.js 8.63 kB {0} [built]
    [28] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/differs/iterable_differs.js 10.8 kB {0} [built]
    [29] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/differs/default_iterable_differ.js 81.3 kB {0} [built]
    [30] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/differs/keyvalue_differs.js 10.5 kB {0} [built]
    [31] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.js 48 kB {0} [built]
    [32] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/parser/ast.js 55 kB {0} [built]
    [33] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/parser/lexer.js 59.3 kB {0} [built]
    [34] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/parser/parser.js 97.6 kB {0} [built]
    [35] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/parser/locals.js 5.72 kB {0} [built]
    [36] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/exceptions.js 8.78 kB {0} [built]
    [37] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/interfaces.js 5.91 kB {0} [built]
    [38] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/constants.js 9.2 kB {0} [built]
    [39] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/proto_change_detector.js 78.3 kB {0} [built]
    [40] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/change_detection_util.js 35.3 kB {0} [built]
    [41] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/pipe_lifecycle_reflector.js 800 bytes {0} [built]
    [42] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/binding_record.js 25.4 kB {0} [built]
    [43] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/directive_record.js 6.52 kB {0} [built]
    [44] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/dynamic_change_detector.js 71 kB {0} [built]
    [45] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/abstract_change_detector.js 49.5 kB {0} [built]
    [46] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/change_detector_ref.js 11.4 kB {0} [built]
    [47] ./~/angular2/src/core/profile/profile.js 8.08 kB {0} [built]
    [48] ./~/angular2/src/core/profile/wtf_impl.js 4.31 kB {0} [built]
    [49] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/observable_facade.js 611 bytes {0} [built]
    [50] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/proto_record.js 9.82 kB {0} [built]
    [51] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/event_binding.js 1.37 kB {0} [built]
    [52] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/coalesce.js 24.8 kB {0} [built]
    [53] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/jit_proto_change_detector.js 3.43 kB {0} [built]
    [54] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/change_detection_jit_generator.js 70.4 kB {0} [built]
    [55] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/codegen_name_util.js 30.1 kB {0} [built]
    [56] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/codegen_logic_util.js 33.8 kB {0} [built]
    [57] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/codegen_facade.js 2.15 kB {0} [built]
    [58] ./~/angular2/src/core/metadata/view.js 10.7 kB {0} [built]
    [59] ./~/angular2/src/core/util.js 546 bytes {0} [built]
    [60] ./~/angular2/src/core/prod_mode.js 479 bytes {0} [built]
    [61] ./~/angular2/src/facade/facade.js 1.14 kB {0} [built]
    [62] ./~/angular2/src/facade/async.js 21.4 kB {0} [built]
    [63] ./~/angular2/src/facade/promise.js 7.21 kB {0} [built]
    [64] ./~/rxjs/Subject.js 6.22 kB {0} [built]
    [65] ./~/rxjs/Observable.js 5.94 kB {0} [built]
    [66] ./~/rxjs/Subscriber.js 4.44 kB {0} [built]
    [67] ./~/rxjs/util/noop.js 103 bytes {0} [built]
    [68] ./~/rxjs/util/throwError.js 107 bytes {0} [built]
    [69] ./~/rxjs/util/tryOrOnError.js 335 bytes {0} [built]
    [70] ./~/rxjs/Subscription.js 2.96 kB {0} [built]
    [71] ./~/rxjs/symbol/rxSubscriber.js 514 bytes {0} [built]
    [72] ./~/rxjs/util/SymbolShim.js 2.09 kB {0} [built]
    [73] ./~/rxjs/util/root.js 672 bytes {0} [built]
    [74] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 251 bytes {0} [built]
    [75] ./~/rxjs/subject/SubjectSubscription.js 1.46 kB {0} [built]
    [76] ./~/rxjs/observable/fromPromise.js 3.16 kB {0} [built]
    [77] ./~/rxjs/scheduler/queue.js 140 bytes {0} [built]
    [78] ./~/rxjs/scheduler/QueueScheduler.js 1.35 kB {0} [built]
    [79] ./~/rxjs/scheduler/QueueAction.js 1.55 kB {0} [built]
    [80] ./~/rxjs/scheduler/FutureAction.js 1.53 kB {0} [built]
    [81] ./~/rxjs/operator/toPromise.js 750 bytes {0} [built]
    [82] ./~/angular2/src/core/application_ref.js 58.6 kB {0} [built]
    [83] ./~/angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone.js 52.3 kB {0} [built]
    [84] ./~/angular2/src/core/application_tokens.js 6.65 kB {0} [built]
    [85] ./~/angular2/src/core/testability/testability.js 18.5 kB {0} [built]
    [86] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/dynamic_component_loader.js 23.8 kB {0} [built]
    [87] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/compiler.js 8.74 kB {0} [built]
    [88] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/proto_view_factory.js 56.4 kB {0} [built]
    [89] ./~/angular2/src/core/render/api.js 34.5 kB {0} [built]
    [90] ./~/angular2/src/core/pipes/pipe_provider.js 3.55 kB {0} [built]
    [91] ./~/angular2/src/core/pipes/pipes.js 6.73 kB {0} [built]
    [92] ./~/angular2/src/core/change_detection/pipes.js 1.03 kB {0} [built]
    [93] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/view.js 51.2 kB {0} [built]
    [94] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/view_ref.js 15.9 kB {0} [built]
    [95] ./~/angular2/src/core/render/util.js 2.38 kB {0} [built]
    [96] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/element_binder.js 2.76 kB {0} [built]
    [97] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/element_injector.js 170 kB {0} [built]
    [98] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/view_manager.js 62 kB {0} [built]
    [99] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/view_manager_utils.js 48.1 kB {0} [built]
    [100] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/element_ref.js 8.44 kB {0} [built]
    [101] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/template_ref.js 6.97 kB {0} [built]
    [102] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/view_pool.js 6.69 kB {0} [built]
    [103] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/view_listener.js 2.44 kB {0} [built]
    [104] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/view_container_ref.js 18.9 kB {0} [built]
    [105] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/directive_lifecycle_reflector.js 4.21 kB {0} [built]
    [106] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/interfaces.js 21.4 kB {0} [built]
    [107] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/query_list.js 8.98 kB {0} [built]
    [108] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/event_config.js 3.95 kB {0} [built]
    [109] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/directive_resolver.js 19.4 kB {0} [built]
    [110] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/view_resolver.js 15.2 kB {0} [built]
    [111] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/pipe_resolver.js 5.06 kB {0} [built]
    [112] ./~/angular2/src/core/platform_directives_and_pipes.js 4.26 kB {0} [built]
    [113] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker/template_commands.js 23.7 kB {0} [built]
    [114] ./~/angular2/src/core/console.js 2.08 kB {0} [built]
    [115] ./~/angular2/src/core/zone.js 621 bytes {0} [built]
    [116] ./~/angular2/src/core/render.js 1.86 kB {0} [built]
    [117] ./~/angular2/src/core/linker.js 3.33 kB {0} [built]
    [118] ./~/angular2/src/core/debug/debug_element.js 30.4 kB {0} [built]
    [119] ./~/angular2/src/core/platform_common_providers.js 2.37 kB {0} [built]
    [120] ./~/angular2/src/core/application_common_providers.js 6.53 kB {0} [built]
    [121] ./~/angular2/common.js 892 bytes {0} [built]
    [122] ./~/angular2/src/common/pipes.js 4.95 kB {0} [built]
    [123] ./~/angular2/src/common/pipes/async_pipe.js 16.6 kB {0} [built]
    [124] ./~/angular2/src/common/pipes/invalid_pipe_argument_exception.js 2.05 kB {0} [built]
    [125] ./~/angular2/src/common/pipes/uppercase_pipe.js 4.11 kB {0} [built]
    [126] ./~/angular2/src/common/pipes/lowercase_pipe.js 4.08 kB {0} [built]
    [127] ./~/angular2/src/common/pipes/json_pipe.js 3.16 kB {0} [built]
    [128] ./~/angular2/src/common/pipes/slice_pipe.js 10.2 kB {0} [built]
    [129] ./~/angular2/src/common/pipes/date_pipe.js 16.2 kB {0} [built]
    [130] ./~/angular2/src/facade/intl.js 15.1 kB {0} [built]
    [131] ./~/angular2/src/common/pipes/number_pipe.js 20.6 kB {0} [built]
    [132] ./~/angular2/src/common/directives.js 2.17 kB {0} [built]
    [133] ./~/angular2/src/common/directives/ng_class.js 23.5 kB {0} [built]
    [134] ./~/angular2/src/common/directives/ng_for.js 23.1 kB {0} [built]
    [135] ./~/angular2/src/common/directives/ng_if.js 6.34 kB {0} [built]
    [136] ./~/angular2/src/common/directives/ng_style.js 11.3 kB {0} [built]
    [137] ./~/angular2/src/common/directives/ng_switch.js 25.9 kB {0} [built]
    [138] ./~/angular2/src/common/directives/observable_list_diff.js 820 bytes {0} [built]
    [139] ./~/angular2/src/common/directives/core_directives.js 4.5 kB {0} [built]
    [140] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms.js 7.51 kB {0} [built]
    [141] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/model.js 62.7 kB {0} [built]
    [142] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/abstract_control_directive.js 6.67 kB {0} [built]
    [143] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/control_container.js 2.87 kB {0} [built]
    [144] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/ng_control_name.js 17.2 kB {0} [built]
    [145] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/ng_control.js 3.17 kB {0} [built]
    [146] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/control_value_accessor.js 2.16 kB {0} [built]
    [147] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/shared.js 16.5 kB {0} [built]
    [148] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/validators.js 14.8 kB {0} [built]
    [149] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/default_value_accessor.js 7.41 kB {0} [built]
    [150] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/number_value_accessor.js 6.83 kB {0} [built]
    [151] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/checkbox_value_accessor.js 6.34 kB {0} [built]
    [152] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/select_control_value_accessor.js 9.37 kB {0} [built]
    [153] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/normalize_validator.js 1.38 kB {0} [built]
    [154] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/ng_form_control.js 15.4 kB {0} [built]
    [155] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/ng_model.js 12.9 kB {0} [built]
    [156] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/ng_control_group.js 13.7 kB {0} [built]
    [157] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/ng_form_model.js 20.7 kB {0} [built]
    [158] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/ng_form.js 22.1 kB {0} [built]
    [159] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/ng_control_status.js 8.41 kB {0} [built]
    [160] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives.js 9.03 kB {0} [built]
    [161] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/validators.js 12 kB {0} [built]
    [162] ./~/angular2/src/common/forms/form_builder.js 16 kB {0} [built]
    [163] ./~/angular2/src/common/common_directives.js 4.11 kB {0} [built]
    [164] ./~/angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter.js 8.88 kB {0} [built]
    [165] ./~/angular2/src/platform/dom/events/dom_events.js 6.43 kB {0} [built]
    [166] ./~/angular2/src/platform/dom/events/event_manager.js 9.5 kB {0} [built]
    [167] ./~/angular2/src/platform/dom/events/key_events.js 16.5 kB {0} [built]
    [168] ./~/angular2/src/platform/dom/events/hammer_gestures.js 6.3 kB {0} [built]
    [169] ./~/angular2/src/platform/dom/events/hammer_common.js 4.95 kB {0} [built]
    [170] ./~/angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_tokens.js 1.57 kB {0} [built]
    [171] ./~/angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_renderer.js 58.5 kB {0} [built]
    [172] ./~/angular2/src/animate/animation_builder.js 3.19 kB {0} [built]
    [173] ./~/angular2/src/animate/css_animation_builder.js 9.02 kB {0} [built]
    [174] ./~/angular2/src/animate/css_animation_options.js 1.97 kB {0} [built]
    [175] ./~/angular2/src/animate/animation.js 26.9 kB {0} [built]
    [176] ./~/angular2/src/facade/math.js 645 bytes {0} [built]
    [177] ./~/angular2/src/platform/dom/util.js 2.38 kB {0} [built]
    [178] ./~/angular2/src/animate/browser_details.js 8.91 kB {0} [built]
    [179] ./~/angular2/src/platform/dom/shared_styles_host.js 9.57 kB {0} [built]
    [180] ./~/angular2/src/core/render/view_factory.js 49.8 kB {0} [built]
    [181] ./~/angular2/src/core/render/view.js 10.6 kB {0} [built]
    [182] ./~/angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter.js 67.9 kB {0} [built]
    [183] ./~/angular2/src/platform/browser/generic_browser_adapter.js 11.1 kB {0} [built]
    [184] ./~/angular2/src/platform/browser/xhr_impl.js 6.03 kB {0} [built]
    [185] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/xhr.js 1.21 kB {0} [built]
    [186] ./~/angular2/src/platform/browser/testability.js 9.68 kB {0} [built]
    [187] ./~/angular2/src/core/profile/wtf_init.js 598 bytes {0} [built]
    [188] ./~/angular2/src/platform/browser/title.js 2.76 kB {0} [built]
    [189] ./~/angular2/platform/common_dom.js 3.19 kB {0} [built]
    [190] ./~/angular2/src/platform/dom/debug/by.js 4.24 kB {0} [built]
    [191] ./~/angular2/src/platform/dom/debug/debug_element_view_listener.js 12.6 kB {0} [built]
    [192] ./~/angular2/src/platform/browser/tools/tools.js 2.58 kB {0} [built]
    [193] ./~/angular2/src/platform/browser/tools/common_tools.js 9.32 kB {0} [built]
    [194] ./~/angular2/src/facade/browser.js 2.67 kB {0} [built]
    [195] ./~/angular2/compiler.js 982 bytes {0} [built]
    [196] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/url_resolver.js 36.7 kB {0} [built]
    [197] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/compiler.js 9.75 kB {0} [built]
    [198] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/runtime_compiler.js 5.7 kB {0} [built]
    [199] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/template_compiler.js 48.4 kB {0} [built]
    [200] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/directive_metadata.js 36.5 kB {0} [built]
    [201] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/selector.js 55.9 kB {0} [built]
    [202] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/util.js 11.3 kB {0} [built]
    [203] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/source_module.js 7.48 kB {0} [built]
    [204] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/change_detector_compiler.js 15.5 kB {0} [built]
    [205] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/change_definition_factory.js 33.5 kB {0} [built]
    [206] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/template_ast.js 28.4 kB {0} [built]
    [207] ./~/angular2/src/transform/template_compiler/change_detector_codegen.js 2.24 kB {0} [built]
    [208] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/style_compiler.js 18.5 kB {0} [built]
    [209] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/shadow_css.js 64 kB {0} [built]
    [210] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/style_url_resolver.js 6.42 kB {0} [built]
    [211] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/command_compiler.js 63.2 kB {0} [built]
    [212] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/template_parser.js 121 kB {0} [built]
    [213] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/html_parser.js 39 kB {0} [built]
    [214] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/html_ast.js 6.08 kB {0} [built]
    [215] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/html_lexer.js 77.5 kB {0} [built]
    [216] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/parse_util.js 8.45 kB {0} [built]
    [217] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/html_tags.js 45.3 kB {0} [built]
    [218] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/schema/element_schema_registry.js 1.45 kB {0} [built]
    [219] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/template_preparser.js 9.77 kB {0} [built]
    [220] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/template_normalizer.js 20.6 kB {0} [built]
    [221] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/runtime_metadata.js 19.5 kB {0} [built]
    [222] ./~/angular2/src/compiler/schema/dom_element_schema_registry.js 8.43 kB {0} [built]
    [223] ./src/testing/components/testing.ts 1.27 kB {0} [built]
```

Comment: Why don't you just include angular2 as a script tag in your view? In other words, why do you want angular2 to be in the final bundle?

Comment: For simplicity, so I do not have to do any manual including of the various vendor modules I need manually (I might need other non-angular stuff too).

Comment: You could possibly shave a lot of bytes off your final bundle if you just include angular separately. Your vendor scripts can be a part of the bundle.

Comment: But actually most importantly now: I am trying to learn and understand webpack (also), and it would be nice to know why it produces such large files. Will webpack also make my future large app 3 times larger than it needs to be (even if I include vendor modules separately and I use webpack for the app itself only)?

Comment: That's just the way that ES6 modules are used. `import foo from 'foo'` gives you access to foo, but bundlers also pull in the dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although a little unwieldy, Webpack Documentation site has good explanation of what it is. (https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-bower.html)

Assuming that you installed angular2 using bower, the link above compares the sizes Webpack achieves using packages installed via `bower` vs. packages installed via `npm`.

For something like Angular 2, which is still in beta, and probably comes with a lot of middleware, I think you are better off not including it in your final bundle. If you do, your final bundle will balloon in size, leading to a very slow and possibly blocking request.

Comment: I use only npm. Looking at the output that running the webpack command gives, I see only Angular and RxJS (which Angular uses) modules, and by looking at the module names, it looks for me that it includes only what it "should" include. But I might very well be wrong...

Comment: Indeed, it does include what you tell it to in the webpack config. My point is that it is causing your bundle to be massive.

Comment: Hmmm, ok :) I will wait until tomorrow before I accepts an answer (possibly yours). Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: When I have a closer look at various files that come with Angular 2 I actually see there is a non-minified bundle that is the same size as to what webpack produces (and also matches the minified version when webpack is doing minifying)...

Comment: So, I didn't get what is the reason that webpack exposes a fatty bundle? Even after uglification it takes 2.5mb versus browserify + uglyfication that exposes 900kb bundle. So, certain thing in a configuration. Webpack analyzer shows angular2 takes 4.6mb. Thanks for any inputs.