# How to make webpack exclude angular2 modules

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am trying to make a simple Webpack-version the Angular 2 [5 min quickstart tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#).

As it [may be problematic to just let Webpack autmatically include all modules needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906401/angular-2-and-huge-webpack-bundle-js), I am including the vendor scripts from the html "directly", almost just like the tutorial, except that I do not need system.js for a webpack setup, so I am not including that, but I do need the "bundle.js" which webpack produces:

```
<body>

<my-app></my-app>

<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>

</body>
```

If I use this config for webpack, I almost have reach my goal:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/boot.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, exclude: [/angular2/], loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ],
    noParse: [/angular2/]
  }
};
```

Without the noParse, webpack would include 223 modules, which by itself is as it should be, but for some strange reason this results in a problematic huge bundle file (see link above). With noParse I am almost reach my goal, but not completely, it still include two angular-modules that I do not want webpack to include:

```
   [0] ./src/boot.ts 195 bytes {0} [built]
   [1] ./~/angular2/platform/browser.js 13.1 kB {0} [built]
   [2] ./src/myapp/components/myapp.ts 1.27 kB {0} [built]
   [3] ./~/angular2/core.js 4.54 kB {0} [built]
```

I do not want webpack to include any Angular 2 modules (as I already have included that). It is probably included because that my two own-made modules uses these two modules. But how can I make webpack ignore these? My `noParse` (or the `exclude`) is not helping here...

Comment: Refer this link. Even though it uses Visual Studio 2015, same technique can be used with any editor http://www.mithunvp.com/angular-2-in-asp-net-5-typescript-visual-studio-2015/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you take a look at `IgnorePlugin` https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#ignoreplugin

What you are saying could be achieved by doing something like this:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/angular2$/)
  ]
};
```

Comment: Indeed! Did have to remove the `$` (after `angular2`), but now I can remove my `noParse` (and my `exclude` attempt). Thank you (again) @frishi, for your help :)